# Insufficient privileges as a definer of package

Tags: oracle-12c, procedure-definition

I cannot run a procedure within a package with a user that also defined it unless I specify "authid current_user" for some reason. Here is my original code that produces insufficient privileges error

```
create or replace package hr.table_pkg 
is 
    procedure make ( p_table_name varchar2, p_col_specs varchar2);
end  table_pkg;

create or replace package body hr.table_pkg is

  procedure  make  ( p_table_name varchar2, p_col_specs varchar2) is 
    sql_stmt varchar2(32767);
    begin
      sql_stmt := 'Create table '|| p_table_name||' ('||p_col_specs||')';
      dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
      execute immediate sql_stmt ;
  end make ;
end table_pkg;
/
```

So the user that defines the package is HR. when I query view USER_OBJECTS I can see the package and the body aswell

but when I, as the HR user try to run

```
execute table_pkg.make('my_contacts','id number(4), name varchar2(40)');
```

I'm gonna get an error that I cannot create the table. It also does not work when I change the procedure in the body to create the table in a specific schema HR:

sql_stmt := 'Create table **hr.**'|| p_table_name||' ('||p_col_specs||')';

the call to the procedure only works when I recompile the header of the package to

```
create or replace package hr.table_pkg 
authid current_user 
is
```

Can please anyone explain to me what am I missing, I do not get why the definer ( HR user) cannot run the procedure with definer rights

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a procedure that executes with the *current_user*'s authorisation, then the *current user* must be able to do everything that the Procedure wants to do.

When you compile a procedure that executes with the *definer*'s authorisation, then the *owner of that procedure* must be able to do everything that the Procedure wants to do.

Any and all privileges needed by such a procedure must be directly granted to the owning account; they *cannot* be conferred through a Role, even if that Role is granted "by default".

You probably need to grant "create table" to the account that owns the procedure.

That said, having a procedure to spin up tables at random strikes me as a slightly odd thing to want to do.

Comment: thanks, after I granted create table to HR it works. Not sure how that works because I was able to create tables with that user before outside of the procedure.
Regarding "it is an odd thing to do" - it was an exercise in an education

Comment: It may be that the HR account has a Role granted to it that confers the "create table" privilege.  That works just fine interactively but /not/ when defining a procedure.  Privileges /have/ to be granted directly to the owning account.